# Query in C# windows application showing error

Tags: sql

```
SELECT        a_id, c_id, company, address, phone, date, time, place
FROM            app
WHERE        (LTRIM(RTRIM(company)) =  'YOKOGAWA INDIA LIMITED'
```

ERROR : Showing error has incorrect syntax near YOKOGOWA INDIA LIMITED

Comment: you are giving a tiny amount of information on your problem with absolutely no context, you need to expand your question significantly

Answer (score 6):

You're missing a close paren in your `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT        a_id, c_id, company, address, phone, date, time, place
FROM            app
WHERE        (LTRIM(RTRIM(company))) =  'YOKOGAWA INDIA LIMITED'
```

Answer (score 1):

The `where` should be :

```
WHERE        
  (LTRIM(RTRIM(company))) =  'YOKOGAWA INDIA LIMITED'
```

**Edit**

The [LTRIM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177827.aspx) removes the first spaces in the varchar. So if you have a statement like this:

```
SELECT LTRIM('     Remove the first spaces')
```

will return:

```
'Remove the first spaces'
```

The [RTRIM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178660.aspx) will remove the last spaces in a varchar. So if you have a statement like this:

```
SELECT RTRIM('Remove the last spaces     ')
```

will return:

```
'Remove the last spaces'
```

if you what to remove all the spaces in a varchar. I would suggest using [replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862.aspx)

```
SELECT REPLACE('Remove all spaces please',' ')
```

This will return

```
Removeallspacesplease
```

So if you are not sure if the string contains spaces I would go with a [LIKE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx). Something like this:

```
WHERE        
   company LIKE '%YOKOGAWA INDIA LIMITED%'
```

Comment: two space is there '  YOKOGAWA INDIA LIMITED' ltrim and rtrim is not triming how to overcome this error " no records is selected.

Comment: select * from app where (ltrim(rtrim(company)))='" + comboBox1.Text + "' and (ltrim(rtrim(address)))='"+comboBox2.Text+"'',''"+comboBox3.Text+"'", connection

Answer (score 1):

You have an unmatched left paren in your WHERE clause. Your query should look like this:

```
SELECT        a_id, c_id, company, address, phone, date, time, place
FROM            app
WHERE        LTRIM(RTRIM(company)) =  'YOKOGAWA INDIA LIMITED'
```

Comment: Its automatically generating in C# query,then its not triming no records is selected

Comment: This is my actual coding :select * from app where (ltrim(rtrim(company)))='" + comboBox1.Text + "' and (ltrim(rtrim(address)))='"+comboBox2.Text+"'',''"+comboBox3.Text+"'", connection

Comment: MY data is '  YOKOGAWA INDIA LIMITED' 'DELHI,DELHI'

Comment: BRIAN i Try that not worked in C# windows application

Comment: @deenadayalan Why aren't you also trimming your combo box text?

Comment: sorry i used same query wat you told but my system is full of virus

Comment: In my application my data is feeded with spaces also ... so i try to remove those spaces... which help to retrieve my record